# Equilibrium of rigid body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, statics, equilibrium

> A uniform beam $AB$ of length $2l$ rests with end $A$ in contact with rough horizontal ground. A point $C$ on the beam rests against a smooth support. $AC$ is of length $\frac{3l}{2}$ with $C$ higher than $A$, and $AC$ makes an angle of $60$ degree with the horizontal. If the beam is in limiting equilibrium, find the coefficient of friction between the beam and the ground.

Can anyone draw out the diagram for me ? I can't visualize it.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I draw one for you,hope it helps!
[image]